# Connecting Android to itself

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

How can I connect my Android to itself?

On a PC you use localhost or 127.0.0.1

I have two apps that are supposed to live on different devices. One talks to the other after you put in its counterpart's IP address.

I want these two apps to coexist on one device. I thought it would be easy, since on a PC you just use localhost:port and everything just works through the loopback interface.

Well, this isn't working on Android. Is there an equivalent?

Googling just shows up web devs wanting to point Android to thier local PC dev environment which is not what I want.

Comment: Since apps "talk" to an IP address on a specific port, could you check if those two apps use the same port when listening? Is one supposed to talk and the other to listen? Are they able to do both things?